# Why doesn't this compile? anonymous class + anonymous object c++17

Tags: c++, anonymous-class, anonymous-objects

**Question:** Why aren't anonymous object of anonymous classes allowed by visual c++17?

Anonymous objects are allowed (I think it's just a temporary in this case?):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

int main()
{
    class ConcreteFoo : public Foo
    {
    public:
        int bar() override
        {
            //some operation
        }
    };
    ConcreteFoo{}.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Anonymous classes are allowed:

```
int main()
{
    class : public Foo
    {
    public:
        int bar() override
        {
            //some operation
        }
    } myFoo;
    myFoo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Both together is not allowed:

```
int main()
{
    class : public Foo
    {
    public:
        int bar() override
        {
            //some operation
        }
    }{}.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why not? I am using **visual c++17**.

The errors are:

```
1>c:\users\peter\downloads\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup.cpp(37): warning C4094: untagged 'class' declared no symbols
1>c:\users\peter\downloads\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup.cpp(37): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\peter\downloads\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup\nationsgamemockup.cpp(37): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
```

Comment: *"(I think it's just a temporary in this case"* exactly, and you cannot declare a temporary.

Comment: The class is con complete untill you reach the `}/*possible name*/;` and you can't construct an incomplete type.